# How to use _rowclass attribute in Openlaszlo?

Tags: openlaszlo

I am facing problem with the usage of _rowclass attribute in Openlaszlo.

I am getting error when i use this code:

```
 <include href="../lps/components/base/basegridrow.lzx"/>
 <class name="EventManager" extends="basegridrow" 
 fgcolor="$path{'couleurdata:/couleur/FormulaireColorFontTexte/text()'}">
 <grid _rowclass="Eventmanager">
```

Error: Attribute _rowclass must be declared for grid type.

I included the basegridrow.lzx in the canvas tag, but still i am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

There two problems with your code:

1. You call the class EventManager, but set _rowclass to Eventmanager, not using the same camel-case spelling.
2. The _rowclass attribute expects the classname with the package declaration added. Therefore, if your classname is eventmanager, you can set _rowclass="lz.eventmanager".

Here's an example code which does not display a grid, but compiles without any problems in OpenLaszlo trunk 5.0:

```
<canvas>

  <include href="base/basegridrow.lzx"/>
  <class name="eventmanager" extends="basegridrow" 
        fgcolor="$path{'couleurdata:/couleur/FormulaireColorFontTexte/text()'}" />

  <grid _rowclass="lz.eventmanager"/>

</canvas>
```

Hope that helps,

Raju